# Service provider framework in java

Tags: java

As per the book "Effecive java" what does the statement "***The class of the object returned by a static factory method need not even exist
at the time the class containing the method is written***." means in following paragraph:

The class of the object returned by a static factory method need not even exist
at the time the class containing the method is written. Such flexible static factory
methods form the basis of service provider frameworks, such as the Java Database
Connectivity API (JDBC). A service provider framework is a system in which
multiple service providers implement a service, and the system makes the implementations
available to its clients, decoupling them from the implementations

Answer (score 9):

> As per the book "Effecive java" what does the statement "The class of
>   the object returned by a static factory method need not even exist at
>   the time the class containing the method is written." means in
>   following paragraph:

A good way to explain what is meant by this sentence is to consider the `EnumSet` type, which is a class in the `java.util` package.

`EnumSet` is an abstract class without any accessible constructors.  In order to get an `EnumSet` instance, the programmer uses one of its static factory methods, eg. `EnumSet.of( ... )`.  For example:

```
Set<MyEnum> s = EnumSet.of(MyEnum.FIRST_CONSTANT);
```

The object returned by the `of()` method does not have an implementation type of `EnumSet`.  Rather, the implementation type depends on the `MyEnum` class.  If `MyEnum` has 64 or fewer constants, then the type of the object returned by `of()` is `RegularEnumSet`.  If `MyClass` has more than 64 constants, the type of the object returned is `JumboEnumSet`.  The actual type of the object returned, however, is of no interest to the programmer.  All he or she cares about is getting some type of object that adheres to the `EnumSet` contract.

Now, let's say that, oh, five years later the Java language architects decide that it would be important to have another `EnumSet` implementation type, say, just for example, a cached enum implementation for classes with very large numbers of constants (more than 1024).  They write this class to follow the `EnumSet` contract and call it:

```
final CachedEnumSet extends EnumSet {
    :
    :
}
```

Even though `CachedEnumSet` didn't exist when `EnumSet` was written, the fact that the use of static factories enabled a contract-based implementation system enabled the Java architects to add this new implementation years later.

Now, when a client invokes `EnumSet.of()`, he or she could get a `RegularEnumSet` object, a `JumboEnumSet` object, or the new `CachedEnumSet` object, but they wouldn't care because the object they get is still a subtype of `EnumSet` and is governed by its contract.

Answer (score 2):

A factory method is generally going to be returning a class that implements an interface (or extends a class, same result either way). But the actual class to be returned may be defined dynamically. In that case, the class to be returned doesn't need to exist when the factory method is written.

May be easiest by example. The JDBC example is something like DriverManager - you provide a database connection URL. From that URL, the DriverManager needs to figure out which class to return. If you're using an Oracle database, it creates an Oracle driver class (which implements the JDBC APIs), even though DriverManager doesn't know anything about Oracle specifically.

As a general case, let's say our factory method returns interface AA. The implementation of the factory method might read a configuration file that defines the class to create, then use reflection to create that class at runtime. The defined class just needs to exist in the CLASSPATH. The factory method knows how to create it, but the implementation hadn't existed at the time the factory method was written.

There are lots of everyday examples where this sort of thing occurs: JDBC providers, custom logging appenders, XML providers.